# Need R Help for ordering time objects

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column as time. When I do

```
data1$Time = as.factor(data1$Time)
Ti = levels(data1$Time)
```

For now, R defaults the order as:

```
"1:00:00 AM" "1:00:00 PM" "1:01:00 AM" "1:01:00 PM"...
```

I need to change that to the order as

```
"12:00:00 AM", "12:01:00 AM", ...
```

i.e. the default order.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Why would you want time to be a factor?

Comment: You need a time class, e.g. `chron::times`.

Comment: Actually, I have, say, data of 10 days and I need to bring together the data of one day in row and the columns should be time. So, for each day, I need to check if the data is available for that time of that day, if yes, put the Data, else NA. I have the rest of it sorted out. But, my columns are now ordered in "1:00:00 AM" "1:00:00 PM" "1:01:00 AM" "1:01:00 PM". I want the default ordering. I know that one brute force will be to find the order of this permutation respect to that original one but that will be tedious, I don't want to take that path.

Comment: Please provide enough data that demonstrates your problem and also show what the expected result (of that data) should look like.

Comment: you can provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(data1))` ; Thus we are able to help you with the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must check [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) package.

You also can use `as.POSIXlt(x, format="%H:%M:%S")` to transform your date into a POSIXlt object and then you can use `order()` to sort them.